# Passing a defaultdict into a df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, defaultdict

I am trying to import a txt file with states and universities listed in it.  I have utilized defaultdict to import the txt and parse it to where I have a list whereby universities are attached to the state.  How do I then put the data into a pandas dataframe with two columns (State, RegionName)?  Nothing thus far has worked.

I built an empty dataframe with:

```
ut = pd.DataFrame(columns = {'State', 'RegionName'})
```

and have tried a couple of different methods but none have worked.

```
with open('ut.txt') as ut:
    for line in ut:
        if '[edit]' in line:
            a = line.rstrip().split('[')
            d[a[0]].append(a[1])
        else:
            b = line.rstrip().split(' ')
            d[a[0]].append(b[0])
        continue
```

This gets me a nice list:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'State': ['edit]', 'School', 'School2', 'School3', 'School4', 'School5', 'School6', 'School7', 'School8'],
```

The `edit]` is part of the original txt file signifying a state.  Everything after are the towns the schools are in.

I'd like to build a nice 2 column dataframe where state is the left column and all schools on the right...

Comment: I tried this:df = pd.DataFrame([(k, v[1]) for k, v in d.items()], 
                   columns=['State', 'RegionName'])                                                              but it is giving me one state and one school and sckipping to the next state.  how do I iterate through all of the schools?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I would recommend you editing your question to work on the formatting to make it more readable. Check out [how to format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Solved it:new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.RegionName.tolist(), index=df.State).stack()
new_df = new_df.reset_index([0, 'State'])
new_df.columns = ['State', 'RegionName']

Comment: Thanks technogeek1995 for edits.  Will correct it next time.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the following dictionary

```
data_dict = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
```

Considering that from that dictionary you want to create a dataframe and name the columns `State` and `RegionName`, respectively, the following will do the work

```
data_items = data_dict.items()

data_list = list(data_items)

df = pd.DataFrame(data_list, columns = ["State", "RegionName"])
```

Which will get

```
[In]: print(df) 
[Out]:
  State  RegionName
0     a           1
1     b           2
2     c           3
```

If one doesn't pass the name of the columns when creating the dataframe, considering that the columns have the name `a` and `b` one can rename the columns with [`pandas.DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)

```
df = df.rename(columns = {"a": "State", "b": "RegionName"})
```

---

If the goal is solely reading a txt file with a structure like this

```
column1 column2
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

Then the following will do the work

```
colnames=['State', 'RegionName'] 

df = pd.read_csv("file.txt", colnames, header=None)
```

Note that if the name of the columns is already the one one wants use just the following

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.txt")
```